# ReactJS stuck on "Starting the Development server..." on Docker container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm using Windows Docker to deploy my React applications. I came across a problem when I am deploying a certain application, it gets stuck in the "Starting the development server ..." phase. It past 1 hour and still does not change.

Here's a snipped from the Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
RUN npm install axios --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

To build the image, use the command: **docker build -t react_project:dev .**

To create a container I used this command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v react-v:/app -v /app/node_modules `
-v C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SSSF\Images_IPMA:/app/public/ipma_images `
-v D:\Images_cameras\CameraRib31Jan:/app/public/camera_images/CameraRib31Jan `
-v D:\Images_cameras\CameraRibUMa:/app/public/camera_images/CameraRibUMa `
-v D:\Images_cameras\CameraRPiCam1:/app/public/camera_images/CameraRPiCam1 `
-v D:\Images_cameras\CameraRPiCam2:/app/public/camera_images/CameraRPiCam2 `
-v D:\Images_cameras\CameraUnifi:/app/public/camera_images/CameraUnifi `
-v D:\Data\ImagesScanner:/app/public/camera_images/ImagesScanner `
-p 8831:8831 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true vimetri:dev
```

They have many volumes redirected because they serve to show images in those folders to my React app. Those folders contain thousands of images and I don't know if that is causing to get stuck.